# Trying to repeat a field with iterating names in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

The HTML

```
<div class="repeatable">
  <a href="#" class="more">More</a>
  <fieldset class="intro_clergy_">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input class="title_" type="text" name="intro_clergy_title_1" /><br />

      <label>Name</label>
      <input class="name_" type="text" name="intro_clergy_name_1" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
$('.repeatable').each(function(){
    var group = this;

    var nameStructure = $(" > fieldset", group).attr("class");

    $(" > .more", this).click(function(){
        $(" > fieldset", group).clone().appendTo(group).children().attr("name", nameStructure + $(this).attr("class") + "1");
        return false;
    })


})
```

So what I am trying to do is whenever anyone clicks the "More" button, it adds a new field.  I have it working except for that I need to take the class name of fieldset and the input and insert as the input name.  If you look at what I tried to do, you would know that I got intro_clergy_more, because `this` is actually the more link.  I need help trying to figure out how I can specifically call the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('.repeatable').each(function(){
    var group = this;

    var nameStructure = $(" > fieldset", group).attr("class");

    $(" > .more", this).click(function(){
        $(" > fieldset", group).clone().appendTo(group)
            .children("input").each(function(){
                $(this).attr("name", nameStructure + $(this).attr("class") + "1");
            })
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Yeah, one more problem though and I will check your answer.  It doubles the amount that is in there.  I tried ':first-child' but it only broke the code.  How do you think that would be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "doubles the amount"? Use jsfiddle for showing example. Do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/RtQKC/1/ ?

Comment: Never mind, just found the issue.  Thanks for the help though.